# What close reason should I use when closing a question for requesting resources?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, moderation, flagging

I have recently flagged a few questions asking for resources for learning English, which is off-topic per [our Help section's on-topic page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

As a link to [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) is not provided among the "*This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*" list of alternative sites (visible only when flagging through the review queue at my current reputation level), I wonder what I should flag these questions as.
Can I put them under '*Needs details or clarity*', or should I write a custom message under '*In need of moderator intervention*'?

Alternatively, could a moderator add that link to the mentioned list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flag them for migration to here (that is, English Language Learners Meta). We have plenty of [resource-request](/questions/tagged/resource-request) questions, so they are likely to be duplicates, but for migration that does not matter.

Comment: Question: Does the resource-request flag always mean the question will be migrated? How I wish SE was more transparent. Otherwise, how to ask for migration?

Comment: @Lambie you can vote to close -> A community specific reason -> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: Yep, I know that. Thanks. There is no specific way to ask for migration.

Comment: @Lambie Mods can migrate a question anywhere in the SE network, so flagging something with a note to that effect could work, if the Mod agrees.

Comment: @gotube But "flagging" doesn't count as a CV. I don't understand why we can CV if something should be migrated to Meta but can't if something needs to be migrated to another site; that doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan If you want it migrated, flag it. If you *also* want to close vote it, then do so and choose the "Other - add a comment" option. The purpose of not allowing users to migrate questions anywhere on the SE network is that they'd so often migrated to the wrong place, then returned as closed for being off-topic for that site.

Comment: @gotube That makes sense, thanks. I was avoiding the "other--add a comment" option because other people had commented first so there was no need for me to do so also, but I guess I can just write a junk comment and then immediately delete it.